# jquery Label Insertion Problem in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, safari

I am inserting a label after a field to show the user an error message.  The problem is after it is first inserted, it's top half is cut off then when you tab out of the field it fixes itself.  There is no problem at all in FireFox.

I have deployed the form to: http://thredup.atomicvapor.com/regtest/index.html

I have also posted the code: http://thredup.atomicvapor.com/regtest/regtest.zip

I appologize in advance for the uncommented jQuery.  Bad habits die hard.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: the markup would be good. Are you floating the elements?

Comment: Posting the code will help debug the issue.

Comment: Just posted the code.  I am completely stumped on this!

Comment: What version of Safari?  I am using Safari 4 and do not see a problem.

Comment: Safari 4.0.2
It's not the end of the world but just odd that it's happening on my browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that you are spelling position wrong in your css file.

line 69, 76,92...

`poisition:relative;`

You have one to many i's in there.

Try:

`position:relative;`

Comment: That did it.  Such a weird buggy behavior for that mistake.  THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!